# How to reference libraries from libs folder in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to make a reference to my libraries in my libs folder but they do not show up when i click Android -> properties -> Library -> Add list.

Here is a screenshot of where the folder are and how the directory is structured.

[image]

Comment: Read [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) for referencing Android project library. Edit: If it's JAR library, right-click your project, choose Android-Properties-Java Build Path-Libraries. Then add External JARs.

Comment: They are not jar libraries. they are all folders... But they do not appear when I go to 'Add' them. Only my workspace folders appear.

Comment: Then I think those are library projects. Just follow the link I provide. http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: I did. They do not appear when I go to 'Add' them. Only my workspace folders appear.